# needing to click twice with jquery toggle

Tags: jquery

I must have some problem with my method of toggling, but I'm getting an issue where once my toggle is activated I have to click each button twice to get an action. Im using a class to assign the toggle function to two links.

```
$(function() {
    $(".partyToggle").toggle(
        function() { 
            $("#wheres-the-party").animate({"height": "450px", "margin-bottom": "0px"}, 500); 
            $("#mapCta").delay(500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
            $(".partyToggleClose").delay(500).animate({"height": "50px"}, 500); 
        },
        function() { 
            $("#wheres-the-party").delay(500).animate({"height": "200px", "margin-bottom": "0"}, 500); 
            $("#mapCta").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
            $(".partyToggleClose").delay(500).animate({"height": "0"}, 500); 
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Can you let us know what other scripts are on the page? Everything seems to be working as it should [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVPj9/).

Comment: actually, your second toggle doesn't do anything.

Comment: UPDATE: I believe my issue may have to do with the two toggles not being connected. Thus the need to click twice. How do I fix this?

Comment: By "second toggle" do you mean the element with class `partyToggleClose`? Your code only defines one element to which a `toggle` handler is attached - the element with class `partyToggle`. Where is the code for your second toggle handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need 
`$(".partyToggle").unbind('click');`
before the function.